# How can I remove "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';  

function App() {

  const [userNameReg, setUserNameReg] = useState('')
  const [passwordReg, setPasswordReg] = useState('')

  const register = () =>{
    Axios.post("http://localhost3001/register", {
      username : userNameReg,
      password : passwordReg,
    }).then((res) =>{
      console.log(res);
    });
  };
```

1. **POST http://localhost3001/register net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**
2. **Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error**

- at createError (createError.js:16)
- at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the URL isn't formatted correctly. This should work:

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';  

function App() {

  const [userNameReg, setUserNameReg] = useState('')
  const [passwordReg, setPasswordReg] = useState('')

  const register = () =>{
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/register", {
      username : userNameReg,
      password : passwordReg,
    }).then((res) =>{
      console.log(res);
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: Thank you. It's worked properly.  But Data does not go to the data base.

Comment: Thank you. It's worked properly.  But Data does not go to the database.

Comment: If you are getting your API response successfully then this is something you need to look at at your Back-end . @ThanukshiWickramasinghe

Answer (score 0):

It seems u are missing `:` in URL

```
Axios.post("http://localhost3001/register", {...
```

It should be:

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/register", {...
```